# Exporting individual packages to a jar - IntelliJ IDEA 10.5.2

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea, export

Does anyone know how I can export individual packages/class files into a jar with IntelliJ IDEA 10.5.2 instead of exporting the whole project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create separate module (right click on the project, then New -> Module) for each packages/classes set you want to be a separate jar.

Answer (score 2):

**For anyone who comes here for the answer:**

You can make the jar using the command line. All you have to do is, run the command in the parent folder of the package you want to export as jar.

e.g You only want to export "mypackage" which is situated in "project/src/mainpackage/anotherpackage/mypackage"

you go into "anotherpackage" and run the following command.

> jar cvf myjar.jar mypackage/

for more information on the jar command, take a look at the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

**NOTE:**

if you make a jar of only the source files i.e. .java files inside the src folder, you won't be able to use it as a library in other projects.

Be sure to make a jar of the .class files(i.e. compiled files) for such use.

Answer (score 0):

You can quickly export the jar package you want to export by installing the Handy Export Jar plug-in.